# Error with 'Git push heroku master' command

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am trying to update the code from my application to my repository and an error appears.

How can I fix it?

```
C:\Sites\ecozap>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Diseño2/.ssh/id_rsa':
Fetching repository, done.
To git@heroku.com:ecozap.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:ecozap.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This error means that the `master` branch on Heroku contains commits that are **not** in your local branch.

You can either pull the missing commits from Heroku and merge them into your local copy:

```
git pull heroku master
```

Or, if you don't care about the missing commits you can force push to Heroku. This will overwrite the remote repo on Heroku with your local commits.

```
git push --force heroku master
```

Make sure you really don't care about them **as you will lose them** from Heroku by doing this. Normally this doesn't matter as Heroku is not normally the canonical repo, somewhere else such as GitHub is.