# Git adding different file types to repo

Tags: git

I am tracking my project on git repo. I've added a python file using the commands below to the git repo:

```
git init
git add --all 
git commit -m "Initial Commit" 
git remote add origin 
git push -u origin master
```

Now I want to add a second file type i.e. text file to the repo however, my Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind. How can I add a second file type to the same repo? Do I need to use branches?

Comment: Presumably someone (or something) else is also pushing commits to that remote. Did you read the rest of the error message, or the numerous resources referring to it?

Comment: It's just me using the repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files are in the same folder in your local working directory. Using the same method above will allow you to push different file types to git repo