# git push origin master non-fast-forward

Tags: git, github

I went through the procedures given when adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line:
1. Change Directory
2. git init
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "First commit"
5. git remote add origin https://github.com/fitz00/Mega-Grazio.git
6. git remote -v

But whenever i run the final command; 
 7. git push origin master
 i always get this error:->

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
An error occurred while sending the request.
Username for 'https://github.com': fitz00
To https://github.com/fitz00/Mega-Grazio.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/fitz00/Mega-Grazio.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind<br>
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

In the repository, there are two (2) auto-generated files LICENSE and ReadMe.md.
Please how do i bypass this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: Why not just `git pull` the remote changes, as git is suggesting?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 git push -u origin master
```

EDIT

I see your repository. It already has some contents and you never pulled that information before pushing. 
What you can do is

```
git clone https://github.com/fitz00/Mega-Grazio.git
cd Mega-Grazio
```

Then add new contents and do commit/push

Comment: @Brendan Have you tried first removing the local repo completely, and then only running the git clone command in this answer?