# git updates rejected error on brand-new clone

Tags: git

I cloned a brand-new repo from our server. I then pulled a new branch from origin. I made a few changes and committed, but when I try to push, I get the "updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind" error. But it's not - it's a brand-new clone, and there have not been any commits made by other devs in the interim. I've tried doing `git pull --rebase` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current), but it just tells me my branch is already up-to-date.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (master)
$ git fetch origin

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (master)
$ git checkout -b estrom/PH-19312 origin/release-18.9.0
Branch estrom/PH-19312 set up to track remote branch release-18.9.0 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'estrom/PH-19312'

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ gitk

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git commit -am "PH-19312 hide calories for literacy item in order history"
[estrom/PH-19312 5ace4de] PH-19312 hide calories for literacy item in order history
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git push
To ssh://stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git
 ! [rejected]        estrom/PH-19312 -> estrom/PH-19312 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git pull --rebase
Current branch estrom/PH-19312 is up to date.

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git pull --ff-only
remote: Counting objects: 28, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
From ssh://stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6
   34e51c0..6a7696a  PH-18381-18.10         -> origin/PH-18381-18.10
   fa0520a..6665db3  develop                -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      PH-19548               -> origin/PH-19548
Already up-to-date.

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git push
To ssh://stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git
 ! [rejected]        estrom/PH-19312 -> estrom/PH-19312 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$
```

ETA: result of `git branch -v -v --list estrom/PH-19312

```
estrom@T460-ESTROM MINGW64 /c/gitRepo/qo6 (estrom/PH-19312)
$ git branch -v -v --list estrom/PH-19312
* estrom/PH-19312 5ace4de [origin/release-18.9.0: ahead 1] PH-19312 hide calories for literacy item in order history
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy-paste the text as text into the question and use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Apologies; I was having trouble copying from the bash window. Fixed.

Comment: Please also post the output of `git branch -v -v --list estrom/PH-19312`.

Comment: @axiac - I'm not familiar with the `-v -v`; what does that do? In any case, added.

Comment: `git help` followed by the command name (`git help branch`) is your best friend while learning Git. Also the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). `-v` is short of `--verbose` and putting it twice in `git branch` makes it list the tracked remote branches. Only one `-v` displays the hash and the subject of the commit they point to.

Comment: OK, so that command shows that origin/release-18.9.0 is ahead by 1. But when I do `git pull --ff-only` it tells me my branch is already up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `git branch -v -v --list estrom/PH-19312` reveals the truth: the local branch `estrom/PH-19312` is tracking the remote branch `release-18.9.0` from `origin` which is, indeed, one commit ahead the local branch. This is why `git push` refuses to work.

On the other hand, you probably don't want to push to `release-18.9.0` but to a remote branch named `estrom/PH-19312`. Then you make a pull request, it is reviewed and, if approved, it is merged into `release-18.9.0`.

The solution to the problem is simple: add `--set-upstream` to the `git push` command line to tell Git to use a branch with the same name on the remote repository:

```
git push --set-upstream origin estrom/PH-19314
```

The problem started when you created the local branch from a remote branch with a different name. To avoid this problem in the future add `--no-track` to the command line when you create branches using `git checkout` or `git branch`:

```
git checkout -b --no-track estrom/PH-19312 origin/release-18.9.0
```

Comment: I just tried the `--set-upstream` command, and got the exact same error as in my original post. And I'm not sure how this problem started, as I created my new branch the exact same way I've been doing it for years, and I've never had this issue before.

Comment: OK, I found my problem. Somehow I had already pushed a previous version of my changes, so there was a remote version of estrom/PH-19312, which I wasn't aware of. I deleted the remote version, deleted the local version, then pulled a new branch off origin/release-18.9.0. I was then able to commit and push my changes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

You probably want to change the *upstream* setting of your branch and rebase:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/PH-19312
git rebase
```

Note that if your Git is very ancient, you won't have `--set-upstream-to`.  You can use `git branch --set-upstream` but you have to be more verbose and use what looks like the wrong order of arguments (this is why modern Git has `--set-upstream-to` instead of `--set-upstream`):

```
git branch --set-upstream estrom/PH-19312 origin/estrom/PH-19312
```

#### Long

There are two problems interacting here, both stemming from the initial `git checkout` command.

#### The setup

Let's look first at this command:

> ```
> $ git checkout -b estrom/PH-19312 origin/release-18.9.0
> Branch estrom/PH-19312 set up to track remote branch release-18.9.0 from origin.
> Switched to a new branch 'estrom/PH-19312'
> ```

The `-b` flag tells `git checkout` to create a new branch.  The next word, `estrom/PH-19312`, supplies the name for the new branch.  The subsequent `origin/release-18.9.0` word specifies which *commit* to check out, and does one more thing when used with `-b`: it tells Git that, by default, the new branch name should have *this* name set as its *upstream*.

It's time to pause a bit and discuss what we mean by "branch" here (see also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).  In this case, the phrase *branch `estrom/PH-19312`* means *the name `estrom/PH-19312` in the `refs/heads` name-space of references*, and the "upstream" is *an entry in `.git/config` concerning the name `estrom/PH-19312`.*  The branch name itself simply acts as a pointer to some existing commit, somewhere in the graph of "all commits ever made" that resides in your own Git repository.  Only those who actually have a clone of the repository can enumerate all the commits, but just making some guesses from the output above, I will draw it like this, which is probably a little off but at least has something right :-) :

```
             o--o--o   <-- origin/develop
            /
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \     \
          \     E   <-- origin/estrom/PH-19312
           \
            o--*   <-- origin/release-18.9.0
```

The round `o` nodes represent commits.  I picked out a few particularly interesting commits and gave them a different symbol so that we can talk about them later.

You then ask Git (via `git checkout -b ...`) to:

- Locate the commit to which `origin/release-18.9.0` points: I've labeled that commit `*` here.
- Extract that commit into the *index* (also known as the *staging area* and the *cache;* see other StackOverflow postings or Git documentation) and the *work-tree*.
- Make a new label, `estrom/PH-19312`, pointing to this commit.

The result is that the graph itself is unchanged, but there is a new branch label, and your HEAD is now attached to that new branch label:

```
             o--o--o   <-- origin/develop
            /
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \     \
          \     E   <-- origin/estrom/PH-19312
           \
            o--*   <-- estrom/PH-19312 (HEAD), origin/release-18.9.0
```

#### At this point you do some work, successfully

You modified some files, `git add`ed them to the index, and `git commit`ed:

> ```
> $ git commit -am "PH-19312 hide calories for literacy item in order history"
> [estrom/PH-19312 5ace4de] PH-19312 hide calories for literacy item in order history
>  1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
> ```

This created a new commit in the commit graph, so let's update the drawing (I'm going to drop the top row entirely since I'm not using it):

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \     \
          \     E   <-- origin/estrom/PH-19312
           \
            o--*   <-- origin/release-18.9.0
                \
                 N   <-- estrom/PH-19312 (HEAD)
```

Note that the *parent* of new commit `N` is existing commit `*`.  This is probably wrong: you started from `release-18.9.0` as seen on `origin` (which your Git remembers as `origin/release-18.9.0`), rather than starting from `estrom/PH-19312` as seen on `origin`.

#### The first failing Git command

At this point you ran:

> ```
> $ git push
> To ssh://stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git
>  ! [rejected]        estrom/PH-19312 -> estrom/PH-19312 (non-fast-forward)
> ```

By default, `git push` tries to push based on the `push.default` setting.  In this case, whatever you have set instructed your Git to push `estrom/PH-19312`.  However, your `push` setting is neither `simple` nor `upstream`.  It might be `matching` (especially if your Git is quite ancient, e.g., Git 1.7 to 1.9 instead of 2.0+).  So your Git thought it should ask the other Git at `ssh://stash.mycompany.com:7999/phi/qo6.git` to have that other Git set *its* `estrom/PH-19312` to point to commit `N`.

But their `estrom/PH-19312` points to commit `E`.  If they set *their* `estrom/PH-19312` to point to commit `N`, they will *lose* commit `E`.  Therefore they say: *No, I will not do that: rejected: non-fast-forward.*  That's what *non-fast-forward* means: the label they have now points to some commit, and you're proposing that they *remove* some commit(s) from their branch while setting their branch to point to your new commit `N`.

Note that if you used `simple` as your `push.default`, *your own* Git would refuse to do the push, because the upstream name is `release-18.9.0` (your `origin/release-18.9.0`).  If you used `upstream` as your `push.default` setting, your Git would ask their Git to set their `release-18.9.0`—it's possible, but I think unlikely, that this is actually what you want.

#### Rebase does nothing because of the upstream setting

When you use `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase`, your Git tries to copy your commit `N` atop your `origin/release-18.9.0`.  As you can see from the graph, your commit `N` already sits atop the commit to which `origin/release-18.9.0` points, so rebase does nothing.

If you change the upstream setting for your `estrom/PH-19312` branch to `origin/estrom/PH-19312`, `git rebase` will copy `N` to a new commit `N'` that sits atop `origin/estrom/PH-19312`:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
         \     \
          \     E   <-- origin/estrom/PH-19312
           \     \
            \     N'  <-- estrom/PH-19312 (HEAD)
             \
              o--*   <-- origin/release-18.9.0
                  \
                   N   [abandoned]
```

This commit is now suitable to send to that other Git for *it* to add it *its* to `estrom/PH-19312`.  I suspect this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, try `git pull --ff-only`

Then push your changes

This will fast-forward your local copy of the branch so it's the same as the remote.

Comment: Nope. I just tried that, and still get the same error.