# Unable to commit my changes and getting this error

Tags: git, github

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: And what seems to be the problem with the message? Can you emphasize which part is unclear to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0):

if you are seeing similar message `REPOSITORY` - your repository name and your `USERNAME` and assuming `master` is current branch

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then, you can do following:

someone pushed new commits between your last git fetch and git push. In this case you need to repeat your steps and `rebase master` one more time.

```
git fetch
git rebase master
git push origin master
```