# I'm getting an error on push command with bitbucket

Tags: git, push-notification, bitbucket

on entering "git push origin master" it is giving the error below:

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://A....'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Emphasis on `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Comment: Is anyone else working with the same repository?

Comment: @choroba no just me

Comment: Have you rebased your working copy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons your `master` branch is out of sync with the distant one `origin/master`.

Backup your work by pulling another branch from your `master`:

```
git branch  master-backup
```

Set your branch to the distant one to sync them:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Find and cherry-pick the commits that you've made:

```
git log master-backup. (Prints your history)
git cherry-pick sha1C  sha1C2 ....
```

Push your branch without any problem.