# unable to push git commits after set up

Tags: git, git-push

I just installed git on my computer following all the informations on their website but I'm kind of stuck.
After commiting my files, I run git push and I get:

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
>   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream.

So I run **git push --set-upstream origin master**, then I get:
[push message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un50P.png).

After that I figured I should do a *pull* first and *push* after, but I get another message: [pull message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7k9C.png).

I followed all the steps and finally got to a message saying:

> branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

After this last one I tried another *pull* and got:

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories.

I don't think I need to say that I'm new to git, it's probably obvious haha, can someone help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you went into GitHub to create the repo, made some changes, then went onto to your computer, initialised the repository and made some changes.

Since the changes from GitHub were never in your local commit history, the two branches have no similarities.

To fix this, if you are **absolutely sure the code you have on your computer is what you want to upload** you can use

`git push --force`

To manually overwrite your git history on GitHub. Be aware this will remove any changes you made anywhere else, but should give you the clean slate to carry on.

In future you should either set up on GitHub then clone the repository to make changes; or set up on your machine then push to an empty repository. This keeps the commit histories in check.

If you want to keep the changes from GitHub and discard your local changes, you can instead use

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Which will **remove all local changes** - so again, be careful.

Comment: " It looks like you went into GitHub to create the repo, made some changes, then went onto to your computer, initialized the repository and made some changes. " This is exactly what I did so I think your answer will resolve my issue. I'll let you know as soon as I get home

Comment: It worked, I've been able to force the push, thanks for the explanation you provided, it was not clear to me on how to set it all up. :)

Comment: @momodjib no problem, when working with git it's always best to ask first, because you can really screw things up if you type the wrong command - glad I could help!

Comment: I agree, I backed up my data before trying, just in case something like a push --force had to happen, so I was safe ^^. Thanks again