# What does "Updates were rejected" mean in Git Bash terminal?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Having trouble with git bash terminal. I am getting this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Eduk8ed/AdBarge.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve git error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532943/how-to-resolve-git-error-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1):

Perform `git pull --rebase origin master` and then try to push.