# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git

Our workflow is such.  We have a branch called `dev` which I can reach at `origin/dev`.  When we do changes, we create a branch off dev:

```
git checkout -b FixForBug origin/dev
```

Now I have a branch called `FixForBug` which is tracking (I think that's the right word) `origin/dev`.  Thus, if I do a `git pull` it'll bring in new changes from `origin/dev` which is great.  Now, when I'm finished with my fix, I push to a remote branch called the same thing.

First I pull down any changes from `origin/dev` and do a rebase:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Then I push the changes to a remote branch of the same name:

```
git push origin FixForBug
```

Now, there's a branch on the remote server and I can create a pull request for that change to be approved and merged back in to the dev branch.  I don't *ever* push anything to `origin/dev` myself.  I'm guessing this is as pretty common workflow.

The first time I do a `git push`, it works fine and creates the remote branch.  However, if I push a *second* time (let's say during code-review, someone points out a problem), I get the following error:

> error: failed to push some refs to
> 'https://github.mydomain.info/Product/product.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

However, if I do a `git status` it says I'm ahead of `origin/dev` by 1 commit (which makes sense) and if I follow the hint and run `git pull`, it says everything is up to date.  I *think* this is because I'm pushing to a different branch than my upstream branch.  I can fix this issue by running:

`git push -f origin FixForBug`

In that case, it'll push the changes to the remote branch, saying *(forced update)* and everything *appears* to be good on the remote branch.

**My Questions:**

Why is `-f` required in this scenario?  Usually when you're *forcing* something, it's because you were doing something wrong or at least against standard practice.  Am I ok doing this, or will it mess up something in the remote branch or create a hassle for whoever has to eventually merge my stuff into dev?

Comment: It seems like the message you are getting is saying that the remote branch FixForBug is ahead of your local branch FixForBug. You should pull down the changes from that remote branch and merge them into your local branch before pushing.

Comment: @mhatch - So basically run `git pull origin FixForBug` before I push to that?  Ok that makes sense.  Feel free to add as an answer!

Comment: for pushing herku if you get this error do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088381/12201407

Comment: [Stack Overflow's most copied question with plain text](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/)...

Comment: If you just cloned this repo try pulling the remote origin. I cloned our repo and forgot to pull the `develop` branch before pushing to it the first time and got past this error.

Comment: In my case I merged a base branch into current (because base branch got many new commits). Then pushed current branch and got this error message. I reviewed branches again and found that another branch merged to current (don't know how). So, I reset current branch and merged with base branch again. Then reviewed branches and pushed without error.

Comment: Not sure but sometimes this error happens when you have a branch in remote with the same name as you're pushing (and maybe PR as created from that branch).
You need to delete the branch and close the PR.

Comment: @NeerajSonaniya, agree. We can close MR/PR and rename current branch or delete remote.

Comment: I had this question so many times! I wonder here who updated the remote branch, since it's probably YOUR branch and nobody made changes to it...

Answer (score 926, accepted):

The `-f` **is** actually required because of the rebase.  Whenever you do a rebase you would need to do a force push because the remote branch cannot be fast-forwarded to your commit. You'd **always** want to make sure that you do a pull before pushing, but if you don't like to force push to master or dev for that matter, you can create a new branch to push to and then merge or make a PR.

Comment: Could you clarify the point "You'd always want to make sure that you do a pull before pushing"? It is clear why "push -f" after rebase of the local branch is required. In this case, won't the rebase of the local be undone by doing a pull w.r.t. the remote before pushing?

Comment: I was thinking about the same, If I pull the files that I rebased then I would be doing a rebase for nothing. Still thanks for the force push, was having issues figuring this out.

Comment: I tried `git push -f` but it says Everything is up to date. any other idea?

Comment: I get ```Sorry, force-pushing to main is not allowed```

Comment: when you `git pull origin/dev` (to bring remote changes in dev or master to local dev or master) and then you do `git checkout FixForBug` && `git rebase dev`, that means whatever changes you had in your local `FixForBug` branch will be put on top of `local dev` branch , Now when you want  do `git push origin FixforBug` fast forwarding on remote cannot be done (because your local changes might have be diverged easily), in that case `git push -f orgin FixForBug` is necessary

Answer (score 532):

`*"The tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart"*` means that there have been changes on the remote branch that you don’t have locally. And Git tells you to import new changes from `REMOTE` and merge it with your code and then `push` it to remote.

You can use this command to force changes to the server with the local repository (). remote repo code will be replaced with your local repo code.

```
git push -f origin master
```

With the `-f` tag you will override the *remote branch code* with your local repo code.

Comment: Better to enable force push incase your branch is protected

Comment: this has actually worked for me after a few minutes of frustration

Comment: I tried `git push -f` but it says Everything is up to date. any other idea?

Comment: i used 'git push -f origin main' and it worked

Comment: Wouldn't this command simply push all local changes to master and wipe the remote changes?

Comment: This doesnt address the OP's situation and/or question; the OP had no changes on the remote branch that the local one did not have.

Comment: yes @Olivier you are right. well, i have tried many things to know what is the reason behind if says code is different on local and remote. but nothing was found, so this command works as we want to do the work.

Comment: who in the world pushed changes, since that's usually the personal branch under a PR and no one else pushes to it?

Comment: @Yashank, you are right! I have used because all I need now is to have the remote repo have everything in my local repo and not the otehr round.

Answer (score 126):

To make sure your local branch FixForBug is not ahead of the remote branch FixForBug pull and merge the changes before pushing.

```
git pull origin FixForBug
git push origin FixForBug
```

Comment: OP stated they already did a git pull and tried pushing. Your answer doesn't apply to OP's question.

Comment: it does apply. git pull and git pull origin it's different things.

Comment: this helped me, as when you have multiple branches locally unless you do 
git pull origin <branch-name>
it will not work.

Answer (score 65):

Set the current branch name, like *master*:

```bash
git pull --rebase origin master
git push origin master
```

Or branch name *develop*

```bash
git pull --rebase origin develop
git push origin develop
```

Answer (score 42):

If you want to avoid having to use `-f`, then you can use just

```
git pull
```

instead of

```
git pull --rebase
```

The non-rebase will fetch the changes from `origin/dev` and *merge* them into your `FixForBug` branch. Then, you will be able to run

```
git push origin FixForBug
```

without using `-f`.

Comment: Rebase is part of our work flow here.  I'll get yelled at if I don't do it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Okay, well then follow the documented procedure of course. From what you describe, you will need to use `-f` because you are *replacing* commit(s) on the upstream repository with different ones that have a different (rebased) history. If you were to use a product such as [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com) then it supports this sort of rebasing code-review workflow without having to use `-f` when pushing. We use Gerrit at work in this way and it works very well.

Answer (score 32):

We can force changes to GitHub using our local repository with the following cmd:

```
git push -f origin main
```

Comment: I was working in my local setup, I have just need to force push my changes to main branch repo, it works fine for me

Answer (score 14):

The command I used with Azure DevOps when I encountered the message "updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind" was/is this command:

```
git pull origin master
```

(or can start with a new folder and do a *clone*)...

This answer doesn't address the question posed, specifically, [Keif has answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-its-remot/39400690#39400690), but it does answer the question's title/heading text and this will be a common question for Azure DevOps users.

I noted comment: "You'd always want to make sure that you do a pull before pushing" in the answer from Keif!

I have also used [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) tool in addition to the Git command line tool.

(I wasn't sure how to do the equivalent of the command line command "git pull origin master" within Git GUI, so I'm back to the command line to do this).

A diagram that shows the various Git commands for various actions that you might want to undertake is this one:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

It must be because of the commit is ahead of your current push.

1. `git pull origin "name of branch you want to push"`
2. `git rebase`

   If `git rebase` is successful, then good. Otherwise, you have resolve all merge conflicts locally and keep it continuing until the rebase with remote is successful.
3. `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 9):

Nothing worked for me in my organization's GitLab. I ended up using the following commands from my featureBranch

Run the following commands in the feature branch

```
git pull origin featureBranch --rebase
```

If you have any conflicts, after resolving conflicts:

```
git rebase --continue
Enter commit messages -> press ESC -> enter “:wq!” and enter
git push origin featureBranch
```

Answer (score 7):

This just happened to me.

- I made a pull request to our master yesterday.
- My colleague was reviewing it today and saw that it was out of sync with our master branch, so with the intention of helping me, he merged master to my branch.
- I didn't know he did that.
- Then I merged master locally, tried to push it, but it failed. Why? Because my **colleague merge with master created an extra commit I did not have locally**!

Solution: **Pull** down my own branch so I get that extra commit. Then **push** it back to my remote branch.

*On my branch* I literally did:

```
git pull
git push
```

Comment: That's true. But I think the situation described in the problem is that there were actually no new changes on the remote as compared to the local branch.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the remote repository already had a branch with the same name as the dev branch that I was working on. I just renamed the branch and pushed the code. It worked for me.

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name
git push origin new-branch-name
```

Comment: This applies to me!

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I have been using for years. But I suppose what we need is an automated fix.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I solved my problem:

Let's assume the upstream branch is the one that you forked from and *origin* is your repository and you want to send an MR/PR to the upstream branch.

You already have, let's say, about four commits and you are getting `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.`

Here is what I did

First, squash all your four commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

You'll get a list of commits with `pick` written on them (opened in an editor).

#### Example

```
pick fda59df commit 1
pick x536897 commit 2
pick c01a668 commit 3
pick c011a77 commit 4
```

to

```
pick fda59df commit 1
squash x536897 commit 2
squash c01a668 commit 3
squash c011a77 commit 4
```

After that, you can save your combined commit

### Next

You'll need to stash your commit.

Here's how:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

Now rebase with your upstream branch:

```
git fetch upstream beta && git rebase upstream/beta
```

Now pop your stashed commit:

```
git stash pop
```

Commit these changes and push them:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "[foo] - foobar commit"
git push origin fix/#123 -f
```

Answer (score 4):

Me help next:

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git apply
git commit -m "some comment"
git push
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Me help next"* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: this worked but I needed to add **git reset --soft HEAD~1** first

Answer (score 4):

If you are really worried about any other approaches, these Steps can help you without any difficutly

1: *Stash* your changes in your *Local Branch* that you want to Push

2: *Rename Your Local Branch* as your Backup for future

3: *Create a Branch of the Same name From your Remote* that will have all the changes

4: *Check out this new Branch* as your New Local Branch

5: *Make and Save the Changes in this Branch*

6: *Commit and Push*

Answer (score 3):

If you use TortoiseGit push dialogue

[image]

Cite source: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html#id692368

> **known changes** - This allows remote repository to
> accept a safer non-fast-forward push. This can cause the remote
> repository to lose commits; use it with care. This can prevent from
> losing unknown changes from other people on the remote. It checks if
> the server branch points to the same commit as the remote-tracking
> branch (known changes). If yes, a force push will be performed.
> Otherwise it will be rejected. Since git does not have remote-tracking
> tags, tags cannot be overwritten using this option. This passes
> --force-with-lease option of git push command.
>
> **unknown changes** - This allows remote repository to
> accept an unsafe non-fast-forward push. This can cause the remote
> repository to lose commits; use it with care. This does not check any
> server commits, so it is possible to lose unknown changes on the
> remote. Use this option with Include Tags to overwrite tags. This
> passes the traditional --force option of git push command.

Answer (score 2):

Over here when you are trying to rebase a dev-feature branch from the master branch (Git version for reference >> **git version git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)** )

**1.git checkout dev-feature**

checkout the feature branch

**2. git pull**

update the head to the latest commit

**3. git pull --rebase origin master**

set up the rebase flag to pull from the master repo

**4. git config pull.rebase true**
in case the reconcile method is not set , since you have 2 divergent branches
**5. git pull**
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev-feature**
if you get the above message it means the branch has been rebased

**6. git push  origin dev-feature**
Push these changes to remote

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to push after a rebase through Visual Studio Code. My issue was solved by just copying the command from the Git output window and executing it from the terminal window in Visual Studio Code.

In my case the command was something like:

```
git push origin NameOfMyBranch:NameOfMyBranch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all of the previous answers and the problem is still not solved, then make sure that the pushed branch name is unique and does not exist in remotes.

The error message might be misleading.

Comment: There is no related answer with my post. If there was then I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The push were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.

When I had such a situation, I just ran:

```
git push -f origin main
```

And it was done.

Comment: `git push -f` will overwrite the upstream changes, and is technically correct.  Most of the time, you want to add your changes to the existing code, so what you need to do is `git fetch` to get those changes, and then `git rebase origin/branchname` to replay your changes on top of upstream. There may be merge conflicts to address, but that way you aren't overwriting someone else's work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the permissions.

You may not have permission to push directly to a main branch (master, development). If you are in an enterprise project, you should push your own topic branch to its remote and submit a merge request (MR).

Answer (score 1):

I have an interesting case: Got this message with a branch that was not yet on the remote, I just created it, edited, commited, tried a push --upstream, bam!
interesting

Answer (score 0):

You must have added new files in your commits which has not been pushed. Check the file, push that file again, and then try pull / push.

It will work. This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Since the branch I was trying to commit was my sub branch under master, I deleted it first from the repository (due to a back referencing issue). I then retried with push and it worked again!

Note: As part of deleting the initial branch, I had all the previous changes in the push I was about to do so no code were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote branch isn't locked.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem in an **automated** environment only, namely Gitlab pipelines and Github actions, when during releases branches are merged and pushed automatically. The only **manual** solution that has worked for me is creating a new branch with the same changes and running the pipeline on the new branch.

I haven't yet figured out how to permenently fix it in Gitlab and Github pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

your local master branch: -> HEAD~N -> updated & new files(can't push to github!)

your github master branch: -> HEAD~N -> AheadNewCommit1 -> AheadNewCommit2 ...

step1. reset to the *HEAD~N*

```
$  git reset --soft HEAD~N
```

step2: pull  AheadNewCommit1 -> AheadNewCommit2 ... to your local master branch

```
$  git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

if you renamed from master to main do:
git push --set-upstream origin main

Answer (score -1):

in android studio on the right bottom checkout to master/origin branch

Answer (score -1):

I was just on the wrong branch, when I did `git checkout main` and pulled, it worked to push.

Answer (score -4):

First, you have to fetch the changes from the remote, only then you will be able to push the changes, In order to do that you have to write the command

```
git pull
```

after that, you will find some conflict, resolve your conflict and then write the command

```
git push
```

This fix is working for me, give it a try and I think due to the conflict on the remote we are not able to push the code