# Git: initialized an empty repository, but can not push or pull

Tags: git

I saw many issues in this context, and tried the solutions provided there but do not work for me for some reason.

So I created an empty project and initialized it using `git init` ([documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)).

`git remote -v` gives me this:

```
origin  https://path_to_/my_project.git  (fetch)
origin  https://path_to_/my_project.git (push)
```

When I run `git pull` I get this error:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

When I run git push origin master I get this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I run `git push -f origin master` (as suggested in many solutions I saw), I get this error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://path_to/my_project.git'
```

Additional info:    `git branch -r` gives me this:

```
 origin/master
```

What info should I check to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the remote branch as upstream of your local branch:

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

Then pull

```
git pull
```