# Git squash changes are being rejected by the remote repository

Tags: git, git-squash

I am trying to squash 3 commits.

- I clone the repository
- I checkout the branch with the commits I want to squash
- I run 'git rebase -i HEAD~3'
- I 'pick' the top commit and I 'squash the second and third one. This is all fine. On my local branch the commits have now been squashed

When I now try to 'push' this is being rejected stating 'Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind'. Now I have not made any changes to any of the files. Does anyone know how I can push this 'squash' to the remote repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since from git's perspective you've removed 2 commits from the tip of the branch. You will attempt to change the history when pushing and to do it you have to `git push --force`.

Answer (score 1):

*Use the force* (`-f`) since you're basically re-writing the history of your branch.
Be careful though you shouldn't be doing this on any long-term branches such as `master` or `develop`.

As an aside, if you're using a git repository management software such as github/gitlab/bitbucket, you could do this via their web interface, with pull requests and using a *squash* option when merging.

Comment: I am using a (local) gitlab. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great! I recommend that you check this out then: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html