# cannot push codes to remote repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I follow the following steps to push my codes.

```
git checkout developement
git fetch origin
git merge origin/development
git checkout <feature-branch-name>
git rebase development
git push origin <feature-branch-name>
```

It gets the following error. I am the only user for the feature branch, so my codes are updated. 
This error only happens after my first push. I do not understand why it shows this error.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://*****@bitbucket.org/jiahaokou/spring5webapp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You should try git pull origin <feature-branch-name>

Comment: @error404 I know this works. But there is no update in remote feature branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you rebased the feature branch, the `-f` flag is required on the push. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind).