# Git updates rejected because tip of branch is behind despite doing it after cloning?

Tags: git, gitlab

Error message:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Let's say that I have a work branch and a master branch

I have just cloned the repository from gitlab and all I want to do is just to

```
git push origin work:master
```

to push all the contents of master

how do I solve this?

I have tried doing `git pull` and it does nothing and I cannot do `-f push` as the master branch is protected.

Comment: `git rebase work origin/master`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind)

Comment: @DaemonPainter That's a bad dup because the accepted answer talks only about `git push --force` and the OP doesn't want force-pushing.

Comment: @phd, but I feel like the question is actually explaining why the issue was caused in the first place. If that's true, the answer is "you must do a force push onto master". Which is not possible in GitLab due to GitLab limitations of "protected branch".

Comment: @DaemonPainter Well, I don't see why the repo needs force-pushing instead of `git pull` (`git pull origin master` probably) or `git fetch` + `git merge` or `git rebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command in order:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master
```

Hopefully, you don't get any conflicts during rebase or else it has to be resolved manually

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin work:master` means *call up the other Git at `origin`, offer them any commits I have on my `work` that they don't have, then ask them to set their `master` to match my `work`.*  That's not wrong, but it's a bit unusual: usually we ask their Git to set their $name (for any $name) to match our $name.  In this case we'd normally ask them to set their `work`, not their `master`.

If you just cloned from them, how did you set up your name `work`?  Presumably their Git recommended that your Git create a branch named `master`, not one named `work`.  If you subsequently ran `git checkout work` and your Git created your `work` based on your `origin/work` that was a copy of their `work`, that would suggest that their `work` is behind their `master`.

(It's possible that the Git over on `origin` is set up to recommend that your Git create a branch named `work` based on their `work`, in which case, your Git will have done that.)

---

In any case, this means that the tip commit of your `work` is *behind* (but possibly also ahead of) the tip commit of *their* `master`.  If you force them to set their `master` to match your `work`, they will "lose" some of the commits off the end of their `master` branch.  That's usually a bad thing, and hence it's rejected by default.

If that's a good thing for you today, you *can* turn your polite request *If it's OK, please set your `master` to _____* (fill in the blank with the hash ID from your name `work`) into a forceful command: *Set your `master` to _____!* (fill in the blank the same way).  If you have permission, they will obey the command, and thereby lose the commits that they had that were "ahead of" your `work`.

If you *don't* want to remove commits from their `master`, figure out the arrangement of commits that you'd like to have, and use `git rebase` or `git merge` to copy or combine any `work` commits you have that they don't, into an arrangement that won't cause them to lose their commits.