# How do I work around this error when trying to push code to an AWS CodeCommitt repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-codecommit

I receive the error: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes before pushing again.

I am new to this whole process and I'm unsure of what I have to do to push code to the repository. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-its-remot)

Comment: check this link by @404 above it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the changes and try again. Because new changes have been already made by someone in the repo.

use this link for more information [fix-git-failed-to-push-updates-were-rejected](https://codewithhugo.com/fix-git-failed-to-push-updates-were-rejected/)

Comment: I have pulled the changes, and I still get this error anyway.

Comment: check the link there are other available options.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a branch and then push to that branch instead of the master. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Then I had to stage all my files before they would get pushed to the repository.

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to merge this new branch with the master.