# Syncing with Visual Studio error; Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes before pushing again

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, branching-and-merging

I have an issue with merging and branching changes to BitBucket repos using Visual Studio 2017.

After a quick search I came across this post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-its-remot)

However my situation is slightly different from the one encountered in the aforementioned post.

I have a branch (lets call `V1.0`) which was released. From there I used the `New branch from local...` option in Visual Studio 2017 which created `V2.0`.

I did this thinking they would be completely separate when it came to pushing changes on each respective branch however `V2.0` is now listed in VS as `V2.0 origin/V1.0`.

I wanted to be able to switch between the branch making changes where necessary however if I make a change on `V2.0` and then try to push, I get the error -

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes before pushing again.
```

Essentially what I want is to have 2 completely separate branches now that are unaffiliated, is there a way I can dethatch `V2.0` from `V1.0` so there is no origin association.

I looked at the `rebase` option but this meant that everything that is different with `V1.0` was getting pulled down and merged into `V2.0` which is exactly NOT what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the upstream branch to v2.0.

```
git push -u origin V2.0
```

Comment: hmm, that might work, any idea how to do that in VS 2017?

Comment: I agree with this. You (the OP) say push but you did not show what command you used. You need to set the upstream for your new branch. And you need to use the command line, I'd say, and stop relying on an inadequate and tricky GUI.

Comment: Good reply. I agree with you.

Comment: @Ebikeneser, you might want to look here for a way to do it in visual studio for now. I would still recommend you familiarize yourself with the command line version of git because it is much more versatile (even if it doesn't come with the pretty commit timelines :P).

Comment: ok, thanks for input i will give this a go and get back to you.