# git --amend --no-edit rejected push

Tags: git, push, git-amend

Today I discovered the `--no-edit` for the `--amend`. However, it leads me to the following problem. Here the steps:

- git clone
- did some changes to the code
- git add .
- git commit --amend --no-edit
- git push origin master

  ```
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://me@bitbucket.org/myRepo.git'
  hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
  hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
  hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
  hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
  ```

Why?

Note: I'm the only one which works on that repo.

Comment: Just a stupid question, have you pulled before trying to push (as the hint suggests) ?

Comment: I have just checked out, It cannot be behind

Comment: When you do `git fetch origin`, does anything come in for the `origin/master` tracking branch?

Comment: No nothing, but why should I fetch if I just checked out?

Comment: I'm trying to see if there are any commits on the remote `master` which you don't know about.  If there _aren't_, then I'm at a loss as to the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.." but how to see differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293263/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind)

Comment: not a duplicate, may have the same error message but the underlying question is different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amending the last commit rewrites history. If that's what you want to do, you can do that with `git push --force`.

The reason it tells you you're behind is because the last commit that exists both locally and remotely (aka "merge base") is the tip's parent. In that regard, you're one commit behind the remote, which already has a commit on top of the aforementioned merge base.