# Git push after reset

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-reset

I committed some unnecessary code so I used:
`git reset HEAD~`

I checked out the files and tried to push my last commits (which were correct). However, I'm receiving error: `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:MyProject/MyProject.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

which is probably since the commit is not reverted correctly since when I do git pull, the commit is back again. 
How can I correctly revert this commit?

additional info: `git status` gives me:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/Mybranch' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.." but how to see differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293263/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to *revert* the last commit, do so with `git revert HEAD; git push`. This creates a revert commit which is pushed on top of the current head.

If you wish to *remove* the last commit, do so with `git reset --hard HEAD^; git push --force`. git protects you against rewriting history, so a forced push is needed to remove commits that already exist in the remote.

Comment: But be careful with `git reset --hard`! Revert is the save way.

Comment: Revert can also cause issues if you merge.

Comment: the key here is `git push --force`.  Be careful, that is a dangerous operation.  It's perfectly fine for daily use, just understand what it's doing