# How do I reset git head to previous local commit and then push that commit to my remote

Tags: git

I have a single branch (master) on my git repo.
I have been pushing commits to my remote repo.

I now want to revert back to a previous commit, and start from there again.

I have run the following:

```
git reset --hard <commit hash>
```

Now the head is at my chosen commit, from here I want to push this chosen commit as the head to my remote master branch.

```
git push origin master
```

It won't work - error message stats

```
'Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart.'
```

How do I checkout a previous commit locally, set the head to be at that commit and then push to my remote repo?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push after reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114300/git-push-after-reset)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+after+reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$ git reset --hard commit` part is okay, you just need to do `$ git push --force origin master`

Comment: Thank you blinkofaneye, that worked pretty much.
Only slight bug is that it gives me this message when i try to update then pull again: 

You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

Comment: maybe you need to do ```git checkout master``` before doing ```git pull```

Comment: This all worked perfectly, thank you. I suppose it would be an even better situation to revert back to an old commit and use that commit going forward but to keep the other commits that i have subsequently overwritten and deleted using this method. This way works fine for me though. Thank you – Jonny 9 secs ago    Edit    Delete